# How to translate Drupal 7 Site from English to Hebrew?

Tags: localization, drupal-7, translate, hebrew

I have a Drupal 7 website. Please tell me how to translate it to Hebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put this link in your header that will take the user to the google translate page

```
       <a href="http://translate.google.com/translate?u=%lookup~url:current%">Translation</a>
```

or visit [this link](http://fosiao.com/content/add-google-translate-drupal) for a code snippet